# .Net Core Lazyloading issue when model built outside the context

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, lazy-loading, ef-core-2.2

Lazy loading of associated entity objects does not work when model is built outside of OnModelCreating and the associated object despite keeping all the methods virtual.

Eg.,

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
{
    if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
    { 
        optionsBuilder
            .UseLazyLoadingProxies()
            .UseModel(new ModelBuilderService().GetOrCreateCompiledModel())
            .UseSqlServer(@"connectionstring",
                sqlOption => sqlOption.UseNetTopologySuite());

    }
}

public class ModelBuilderService 
{
    private static IModel GetOrCreateCompiledModel(IEnumerable<string> modelSupplyingAssemblyPatterns)
    {
        var conventions = SqlServerConventionSetBuilder.Build();
        var modelBuilder = new ModelBuilder(conventions);

        var modelBuilderType = typeof(ModelBuilder);
        var entityMethod = modelBuilderType.GetMethod("Entity", modelBuilderType.GetGenericArguments());
        var pathToUse = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;

        if (!AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory.Contains("bin"))
        {
            pathToUse = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "bin");
        }

        var entitiesAdded = new HashSet<string>();

        if (entityMethod == null)
        {
            throw new NullReferenceException("Cannot find Entity method on DbModelBuilder");
        }

        foreach (var assemblyPattern in modelSupplyingAssemblyPatterns)
        {
            var dataProviderModels = Directory.EnumerateFiles(pathToUse, assemblyPattern, SearchOption.AllDirectories);

            foreach (var dll in dataProviderModels)
            {
                var assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(dll);

                modelBuilder.ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly(assembly);

                var typesToRegister = assembly.GetTypesInheritingFrom<BaseObject>();

                foreach (var entity in typesToRegister)
                { 
                    if (entitiesAdded.Add(entity.FullName))
                    {
                        entityMethod.MakeGenericMethod(entity)
                                    .Invoke(modelBuilder, new object[] { });
                    }
                }
            }
        } 
        return modelBuilder.Model;
    } 
}
```

Trying to find a workaround for this issue since I have a generic solution and the data entities are built outside the Context using "UseModel" method but the lazyloading support goes away for this way and proxy objects are not created for entities fetched from database.

Comment: Can you share the sample model building code? I'm asking because lazy loading proxies are modifying the model, which does not happen when you build it outside.

Comment: @IvanStoev you are right ! Lazyloading proxies adds a convention set only when models are built using using OnModelCreating() method.  Also, the EFCore team confirmed this https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/15532. So, trying hard to find a workaround for this major blocker.

Comment: Indeed. That's why I need to see the model building code in order to figure some workaround (by somehow plugging the lazy loading convention or manually applying what it does on the built model).Actually I see it in the GitHub issue you've posted, but it's good to be here in case I (or someone else) composes an answer.

Comment: @IvanStoev Have updated with the modelbuilding code..

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that lazy loading proxies package uses convention which is executed after the model is built and modifies it. While the external model is built without that convention being in place, so the functionality is not activated at all.

The following workaround is for the latest official EF Core release 2.2.4 at the time of writing. Most likely it would need to be updated accordingly if you upgrade to a newer EF Core version (3.0+) or removed if they fix it.

The [EF Core 2.2.4 code](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/blob/v2.2.4/src/EFCore.SqlServer/Metadata/Conventions/SqlServerConventionSetBuilder.cs#L88) of `SqlServerConventionSetBuilder.Build()` method you are using looks like this:

```
public static ConventionSet Build()
{
    var serviceProvider = new ServiceCollection()
        .AddEntityFrameworkSqlServer()
        .AddDbContext<DbContext>(o => o.UseSqlServer("Server=."))
        .BuildServiceProvider();

    using (var serviceScope = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IServiceScopeFactory>().CreateScope())
    {
        using (var context = serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetService<DbContext>())
        {
            return ConventionSet.CreateConventionSet(context);
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, it uses some trickery, with the most important being the own `DbContextOptionsBuilder`. So all we need is to add `UseLazyLoadingProxies()` call to that builder.

In order to do that, create a private static method with the modified code:

```
static ConventionSet BuildSqlServerConventionSet()
{
    var serviceProvider = new ServiceCollection()
        .AddEntityFrameworkSqlServer()
        .AddDbContext<DbContext>(o => o.UseSqlServer("Server=.").UseLazyLoadingProxies()) // <--
        .BuildServiceProvider();

    using (var serviceScope = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IServiceScopeFactory>().CreateScope())
    {
        using (var context = serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetService<DbContext>())
        {
            return ConventionSet.CreateConventionSet(context);
        }
    }
}
```

and use it in place of `SqlServerConventionSetBuilder.Build()` call, e.g.

```
var conventions = BuildSqlServerConventionSet();
// ... the rest
```

**Update:** Also note that the `ModelBuilder.Model` property returns pending mutable model during the building. In order to get the finalized model *"ready for use by the runtime"*, replace

```
return modelBuilder.Model;
```

with

```
return modelBuilder.FinalizeModel();
```

This method is executed by EF Core infrastructure *"automatically when using `OnModelCreating`"*.

Comment: thanks for providing the workaround @IvanStoev.. I tried initializing the modelbuilder with this conventionSet but it did not work.  As you pointed out, the Lazyloadingproxies package adds proxyconvention only after the models are built.  But, with building models outside the context, we are forced to initialize the conventionset before the models are created and that seems to be root cause of this issue.

Comment: Hmm, I didn't say that - conventions are created at the beginning, just there are different convention types which run on different model actions. The lazy loading proxy convention is just of the types that run on model built. There are 10+ similar conventions which you can see in `conventionSet.ModelBuiltConventions`. Anyway,  too bad if it doesn't work as you say, although I see no reason why it shouldn't.

Comment: I think I found why it didn't work for you - see the update. Cheers.

Comment: you're amazing.. the "FinalizeModel()" method did the magic to make it work.  Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

One workaround for lazy-loading with EFCore 2.2.4 in this scenario is by injecting the ILazyLoader service into an entity.  This method doesn't require entity types to be inherited from or navigation properties to be virtual, and allows entity instances created with `new` to lazy-load once attached to a context. However, it requires a reference to the ILazyLoader service, which is defined in the `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Abstractions` package. Example code for lazyloading a Datamodel with many-many relationship will be as follows:

```
    `public partial class PersonOrganisation
        {
            private Person person;
            private Organisation organisation;
            private ILazyLoader LazyLoader { get; set; }
            private PersonOrganisation(ILazyLoader lazyLoader)
            {
                LazyLoader = lazyLoader;
            }
            public PersonOrganisation()
            {
            }

            public Guid? PersonId { get; set; }
            public Guid? OrganisationId { get; set; }

            public virtual Organisation Organisation {
                get => LazyLoader.Load(this, ref organisation);
                set => organisation = value;
            }

            public virtual Person Person {
                get => LazyLoader.Load(this, ref person);
                set => person = value;
            }
        }`
```